# mysql adding total price of certain products

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, select-query

hi i'm having problems querying a products table at the moment:

i need to display the total cost of all HP and toshiba products..

this is what i have tried so far

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE prod_id LIKE '__hp%'
AND SELECT SUM(price) AS total  FROM products;
```

any help would be appreciated

this is a pic of the products table -->>

[image: products table]

Thank you;

Comment: Mureink answer must be enough, but if in any momento you have a producto named "HP5 Epson bla bla" it will fail. Ideally you should have another column/table to make a relation between products and brand, then make the query using the brand and not the name.

Comment: it still isn't displaying the total cost of al hp and toshiba products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could help yourself a lot if it is clear that the 3rd and 4th characters of Prod_ID are a manufacturer code. HP and TA for Toshiba.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(prod_id,3,2)
      ,SUM(price * on_hand)
 WHERE SUBSTRING(prod_id,2,1) IN ('TA','HP')
 GROUP BY SUBSTRING(prod_id,3,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS total_price
FROM   products
WHERE  prod_name LIKE 'HP%' or prod_name LIKE 'Toshiba%';
```

Comment: @Jmac88 care to be a bit more specific?